# Create file in external storage and open in FileManager Windows

Tags: java, android, android-studio, storage, android-external-storage

My program creates a new html file and sends it to the ftp server.
To do this, I create a local file in the device's memory. Everything works if I create directories and a file manually. As soon as I tried to create directories and a file programmatically, I ran into a problem. If you open Explorer in android studio, the file is created and located in the right directory. But when you try to view the file through Windows Explorer, there is no directory and file. In this regard (as I assume) the file is not sent to the ftp server. I can't solve the problem for many days. I have read many articles on the topics of memory and writing files to them. Please help me. Thank you in advance. I'm new in android developing.

```
public void sendFileIntoFTP(FTPClient ftpClient, String codeRes) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        @SuppressLint("SdCardPath") String sourceFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "timetracker" + File.separator + getYear() + File.separator + getMonth();
//      Log.d("dirFTP", sourceFilePath);
        String fileName = codeRes + ".html";
        File sourceFile = new File(new URI(sourceFilePath));
        Log.d("dirFTP", valueOf(sourceFile));
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        ftpClient.storeFile(fileName, inputStream);
        if (ftpClient.storeFile(fileName, inputStream)) {
            Log.d("dirFTP", "SUCCESS");
        } else {
            Log.d("dirFTP", "ERROR");
        }
        inputStream.close();
    }

    public void createLocalHTML(String codeRes, Context context) throws IOException {
        @SuppressLint("SdCardPath") File internalDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "timetracker" + File.separator + getYear() + File.separator + getMonth());
        Log.d("localDir", valueOf(internalDir));
        String fileName = codeRes + ".html";
        File internalFile = new File(internalDir, fileName);
        Log.d("localDir", valueOf(internalFile));
        if (internalFile.exists()) {
            Log.d("localDir", "file.exists TRUE");
            if (internalFile.canRead()) {
                Log.d("localDir", "file.canRead TRUE");
            } else { Log.d("localDir", "file.canRead FALSE"); }
//            update file in future....
        } else {Log.d("localDir", "file.exists FALSE");}
        if (!internalDir.mkdirs()) {
            internalDir.mkdirs();
            Log.d("mLog", "Directory created in path: " + internalDir);
        } else { return; }
        internalFile.createNewFile();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName, false);
        writer.write(context.getAssets().open("dataTime.html").toString());
        writer.close();
    }
```

Log "localDir":

```
2023-11-14 10:44:44.567  6819-6945  localDir                pid-6819                             D  /storage/emulated/0/timetracker/2023/11-2023
2023-11-14 10:44:44.567  6819-6945  localDir                pid-6819                             D  /storage/emulated/0/timetracker/2023/11-2023/003.html
2023-11-14 10:44:44.572  6819-6945  localDir                pid-6819                             D  file.exists TRUE
2023-11-14 10:44:44.573  6819-6945  localDir                pid-6819                             D  file.canRead TRUE
```

UPD: My permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

I wanna see here my folder, which create programmatically:
[imageFromExplorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVYw5.png)

Comment: `create a local file in the device's memory. ` Ok. Please tell full path of file.

Comment: And before you try to upload a file use File.exists() and File.canRead().

Comment: `internalDir.mkdirs();` mkdirs() can fail. You blindly assume that the directory is made. Better: if(!internalDir.mkdirs()) return;

Comment: @blackapps, full path of file: /storage/emulated/0/timetracker/2023/11-2023/003.html
Added a check that it exists and that it can be read. All true. Also replaced internalDir.mkdir(); with if(!internal Dir.mkdir()) retu;

Comment: Please update your code with the new stuff. What is Android version of used device?

Comment: Updated now. Android 6.0. API 23

Comment: You have two calls to mkdirs(). That will not go. You did it not like suggested.

Comment: Can you show,how it must be? I think i not correctly understand, what you mean.

Comment: I already told you all. But i repeat: if(!internalDir.mkdirs()) return;

Comment: `FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName, false);` You are not using the directory here as fileName is only a file name not a full path to the file. It will probably get created in getFilesDir().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer but an alternative for for your create function.
That function will not always create a file as when the file already exists it just returns.

Also all those if-else's make it quite unreadable. Try to use only if's.

```
public boolean forceLocalHTML(String codeRes, Context context) throws IOException {
    
    String fileName = getYear() + "/" + getMonth() + "/" + codeRes + ".html";
    String subDir = "timetracker";
    
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), subDir + "/" + fileName);

    if ( file.exists() )
        return true;

    File dir = file.getParentFile();

    if ( ! dir.exists())
    {
        if ( !dir.mkdirs() )
            return false;
    }
    
    if ( ! file.createNewFile() )
        return false;

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file.getAbsolutePath(), false);
    writer.write(context.getAssets().open("dataTime.html").toString());
    writer.close();
    
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. The file is still not visible in windows explorer. Apparently the problem is not in the code, but with file access rights. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: After reboot of Android device it will.

Comment: Amazing,it's works)
I am incredibly grateful to you, thank you so much for helping <3

Comment: You should your newly created file let scanned by the mediastore right away. Only a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing "F5" (=update the content) in Windows Explorer, or, if that doesn't help, selecting a different folder and going back to the created folder. If that still doesn't help, disconnect the smartphone from the PC and reconnect it.

Comment: I tried to do the same. It doesn't help